# What is this type of coding called?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to convert some C# code into VB.NET code.

The piece of code is this:

```
        var interactorsAgent = host.InitializeVirtualInteractorAgent(currentWindowHandle, "ConsoleWindowAgent");

        interactorsAgent
            // we will leave default params for everything except bounds and id
            .AddInteractorFor(currentWindowBounds, Literals.RootId, 0, currentWindowHandle.ToString(), "MyFirstActivatable")
            // we define interactor to be an activatable one
            .WithActivatable()
            // we will provide some action which will be invoked when interactor will receive
            // gaze while Engine is in ActivationModeOn
            .HasActivationFocus(id => Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} got activation focus.", id))
```

As I'm having problems convert this monster to VB.NET I wanted to start simple and find out what this type of coding is called.

In VB.NET it would look something like this:

```
Dim v1 As VirtualInteractor =  interactorsAgent.AddInteractorFor(currentWindowBounds, Literals.RootId, 0, "0", "MyFirstActivatable").WithActivatable().HasActivationFocus(
```

To me it looks like one extension leads into the next, and I have no idea what this type of coding is called. Then I could read up on it.

Thank you.

Comment: builder, fluent, etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: You basically just return an instance of the builder for each fluent method so you can chain methods.